# Two target for one <a> tag and display two results in two different div

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Student.php -here i am getting list of students from a specific  Institution in a  tag

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['c_id'])) {  //input field value which contain Institution name
        $val=$_POST['c_id'];
        $sql="select RegistrationId from `students` where `Institution`='$val' ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                   $number=$row['RegistrationId'];

        ?>
        <a href='<?php echo "index.php?StudentID=$number"; ?>' target="index" id="link">
        //getting student id in the dynamic link
        <?php    echo  "$number";
         echo "<br/>";
            }}
         ?>
         <div id="index" name="index"> </div>
         <div id="Documents"> </div>
         <script>
            $(document).on('change', 'a#link', function()
            {
               $.ajax({
                 url: 'Documents.php',
                 type: 'get',
                 success: function(html) 
                    {
                       $('div#Documents').append(html);
                    }
                     });
            });
         </script>
```

In index.php - I am Getting students details based on $_GET['StudentID'] ('a' tag value)

```
        <?php
        $link=$_GET['StudentID'];
        $sql = "select StudentName,Course,Age,Address from `students` where `RegistrationId`="."'".$link."'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo  $row['StudentName']."<br/>";
        echo $row['Course']."<br/>";
        echo $row['Age']."<br/>";
        echo $row['Address']."<br/>";
        }
        ?>
```

In Documents.php -I am getting documents related to the speific student selected in 'a' tag

```
        $link=$_GET['StudentID'];
        $qry =  "select Image,Marksheet from `documents` where `RegistrationId`='$link'";
        $result = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());   
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $image = $row["Image"]; 
        $image1 = $row["Marksheet"];
        echo    '<embed src='. $image.'>';
        echo    ' <object data='. $image1.'width="750" height="600">';
        echo    '  </object>';
        }
```

On click of student id i am trying to get result from index.php to div()
and result from Documents.php to div()
(i.e)two target for one click in  tag

My code only take me to the index.php file result in a new Window
Please Help me to solve this problem
(sorry if my question seems silly i am new to php)

Update:

```
        $(document).on('click', 'a#link', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
                url:"details.php",
               
                type:'POST',
                success:function(response) {
                  var resp = $.trim(response);
                  $("#index").html(resp);
                 alert(resp);
                }
              });
            
          });
          $(document).on('click', 'a#link', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
                url:"index.php",
                type:'POST',
                success:function(response) {
                  var resp = $.trim(response);
                  $("#Documents").html(resp);
                 alert(resp);
                }
              });
            
          });
```

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: I am new to php. thank for your usefull links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `<a>` tag like below :

```
 <a href="#" data-id='<?php echo $number; ?>' class="link"> .. </a>
```

Then , in your jquery code do below changes :

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.link', function(e) {
  var StudentID = $(this).attr("data-id") //get id
  console.log(StudentID)
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "details.php",
    data: {
      StudentID: StudentID
    }, //pass same to ajax
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
      //do something
      call_next_page(StudentID);//next ajax call
    }
  });

});

function call_next_page(StudentID) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    data: {
      StudentID: StudentID
    }, //pass same to ajax
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
      //do something
    }
  });

}
```

And then at your backend page use `$_POST['StudentID']` to get value of student id instead of `$_GET['StudentID'];`

Comment: mam thanks for your response.mam on click the link only the i change see # in url.no any changes

Comment: Does ajax gets called ? Do `alert("in")` inside `$(document).on('click', 'a.link', function(e) {` see if this comes up ..also check browser console are there any error.

Comment: my console is empty .and alert not working. mam my code works.only based on href.its not minding the script onlick

Comment: Not even showing any error in console? Did you add jQuery cdn?

Comment: thank you mam. you are right .jquery cdn problem.thank you very much for your help

Comment: Your welcome ..:) .You  can [vote up and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answer if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it seems that you want to load the two results, one from index.php and one from Documents.php in two separate divs on the same page when the link is clicked.

But you're using a **change** event on the link, not a **click** event. The change event is not fired when the link is clicked, so JavaScript does not get executed and the page loads to the URL specified in the href attribute of the link. So first you need to change `$(document).on('change')` to `$(document).on('click')`.

Furthermore, since you want two results to load - one from index.php and one from Documents.php, you'll need to create **two ajax requests**, one to index.php and the other for Documents.php. In the success function of each of the ajax requests, you can get the response and put it in the corresponding divs.

In addition to this, you'll also need to prevent the page from loading to the new page specified in href attribute when the link is clicked, otherwise the ajax requests fired on clicking the link will get lost in the page load. Thus, you need to add a `e.preventDefault();` to your onclick event handler like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#link', function(e) {

    // Stop new page from loading
    e.preventDefault();

    // Two ajax requests for index.php and Documents.php
});
```

Update: You don't need to add two click handlers for each ajax request. Inside one click handler, you can put both the ajax requests.

**Also your event handlers won't register if you're adding them before jQuery, or if you're adding them before the DOM has loaded. So move your code to bottom of the HTML page, just before the closing `</body>` tag.**

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a#link', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      url:"details.php",
      type:'POST',
      success:function(response) {
        var resp = $.trim(response);
        $("#index").html(resp);
        alert(resp);
      }
   });
   $.ajax({
      url:"index.php",
      type:'POST',
      success:function(response) {
        var resp = $.trim(response);
        $("#Documents").html(resp);
        alert(resp);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="index.php?StudentID=1" id="link">Link</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.please see my update.that still shows result in new page

Comment: i am using this line <a href='<?php echo "index.php?StudentID=$number"; ?>' id="link" > i think this is the reason for getting result in new page.i have no idea replacement for this dynamic link?

Comment: Are you adding this code before loading jQuery or after it? Also you should add event handlers only after the DOM is loaded.. otherwise they may not register and the link will function normally by taking the user to the new page.

Comment: now i just added the <a> tag at last before body.but still no luck.sir

Comment: <a> tag not using the ajax

Comment: Its the **SCRIPT** that you have to move to the bottom. This is because the script executes ON THE A TAG, so it must be declared **after** the DOM (which means all tags in the HTML page for simpilcity) is loaded.

Comment: i moved the script to the bottom sir.i have one doubt even in your example on hover that shows one index.php link .so  on click that will direct to the index.php?StudentId=1.

Comment: You can just make href="#" it doesn't matter because the link's click event is captured by the script.

And for your question 'then what script is for here', you put it there in the first place lol. Why did you put the script there at all?

Comment: if i use # in href .onclick only link appended by this #.thats all.I am using script to get two action in one dynamic href .but nothing is working for me:(

Comment: sorry my fault.jquery cdn problem.now it works well.thank you so much sir